# Xamarin.Android Alternative Colors List

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to make the rows in my `ListView` in alternative colors - `Xamarin.Android` **C#** Project.

Here's my code

```
ListView DialogoList = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.DialogoList);
Data data = new Data();
string[] dialogolist = data.Dialogo(Data.level, Data.Lesson);
DialogoList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, dialogolist);
```

Comment: Create a custom adapter, override GetView and change the color depending on position

Comment: Yea, it works, thanks .. @YorkShen-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

As @Nongthonbam Tonthoi said, you could override the `GetView` color depending on position :

For example :

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var item = items[position];
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);

    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Heading;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.SubHeading;
    view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image).SetImageResource(item.ImageResourceId);

    if (position % 2 == 0)
    {
        view.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.listView_item_bg).SetBackgroundColor(Color.Pink);
    }
    else
    {
        view.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.listView_item_bg).SetBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
    }
    return view;
}
```

For complete code you could refer to this [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/CustomRowView).

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzzPg.png).